# Windows 10 volume converted from MBR to GPT, how to readd recovery command line console?

Tags: windows-10, gpt, recovery-console

I decided to do what you're not supposed to do and convert my MBR install of Windows 10 to GPT. I used Paragon Hard Disk Manager 15 for the conversion, it worked fine, and I managed to get boot working by repartitioning the boot portion of the hard drive and running bcdedit. All is fine there.

However, when I shift+reboot into the Windows recovery environment, I no longer have the option to go to a recovery command console. How can I recreate that recovery environment?

Comment: You understand you can just use an installation disk to get to an identical environment right?  If you use Advanced Startup can you get to it?

Comment: Yes, and that's how I got to a recovery console to fix BCD after the conversion from MBR to GPT. Optimally I'd like to have the same recovery options on the local on-disk recovery. I'm just wondering if there's a way to accomplish that without completely reinstalling.